# Talend - tCacheIn / tCacheOut throws null pointer exception

Tags: talend

I am working on the big data spark requirement where I have to use tCacheOut and tCacheIn. Attached job screen shot is working fine but in one scenario when tCacheOut has nothing to store i.e. filter is not allowing to flow any row to next component, it throws null pointer exception.

[image]

I know, there are other alternatives like write output in disk and read again at the next step but I don't want to do that because disk read and write is always an overhead.

How we can handle null pointer exception in this case?

Comment: Write a condition for null result in tFilterRow in advanced setting and take a reject flow from tFilterRow

Comment: Can you help me to write this condition

Answer (score 0):

Suppose in tFileInputDelimited having 2 columns i.e. name and age. in tFilterRow i have two conditions like name not equals to NULL with AND operator name equals "John". i have connected tFilterRow component to tCacheOut with 'filter' flow.
Now connect a tFilterRow to tDie or tWarn with reject flow.